# cakephp requestAction method View file

Tags: cakephp, view, model, controller

How can i call a `requestAction` method from my `view`, to specific `controller`, which `returns` me results on basis of conditions i mention?

Thanks !

Comment: from Elijan: why would you want to do that from the view? (serious question)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Generally speaking, using `requestAction` is not very performant, because it begins a whole new dispatch process -- in essence your application is handling two requests for every one request made by a user. For this reason, you want to avoid using it as much as possible. That being said, `requestAction` has its uses, and you can mitigate the performance hit using view caching.

It's hard to gauge precisely what you want to do with `requestAction`, but the fundamental concept is you're asking CakePHP to process another request, so you can simply pass `requestAction` any URL your app would handle if it were typed into a browser's address bar (excluding the protocol and hostname). If you wanted to retrieve a collection of blogs managed by your application:

```
  $blogs = $this->requestAction('/blogs/index');
```

You can also invoke `requestAction` by passing it an array of route components, in the same way as you might pass them into `HtmlHelper::link`. So you might retrieve the collection of blogs thus:

```
  $blogs = $this->requestAction('controller'=>'blogs', 'action'=>'index');
```

Insofar as filtering the result-set returned by `requestAction`, it again is done by passing the conditions as part of the URL or route components:

```
  $blogs = $this->requestAction('/blogs/index/author_id:1234');
  // or
  $blogs = $this->requestAction('controller'=>'blogs', 'action'=>'index', 'author_id' => 1234);
```

Note that if you want your requested action to return values, you need the action to handle requests differently than standard action requests. For the `BlogsController::index` action I've been referring to above, it might look something like this:

```
class BlogsController extends AppController{
  function index(){
    $conditions = array();
    if ( isset($this->params['author_id'])){
      $conditions['Blog.author_id'] = $this->params['author_id'];
    }

    $blogs = $this->Blog->find('all', array('conditions'=>$conditions);

    if ( isset($this->params['requested']) && $this->params['requested'] == 1){
      return $blogs;
    }
    else{
      $this->set(compact('blogs'));
    }
  }
}
```

The `if` statement checking the presence and value of `$this->params['requested']` is the key part. It checks whether the action was invoked by `requestAction` or not. If it was, it returns the collection of blogs returned by `Blog::find`; otherwise, it makes the collection available to the view, and allows the controller to continue onto rendering the view.

There are many nuances to using `requestAction` to arrive at the specific results you require, but the above should provide you with the basics. Check out the links posted by **dogmatic69** for additional documentation, and of course there are numerous stacko questions on the subject.

Feel free to comment with any follow-ups! Hope this helped.

Comment: The braces you added are completely superfluous, FYI. If only one statement appears after an `if` or `else`, you don't need to wrap it in braces.

Comment: Except if you like readability and abide by strong coding standards. Most of my if statements are amended later in time. Adding new statements means I had to add the braces. Forgetting to do that can make more debugging work, so I decided never to leave them out again. Except if I absolutely know that NO CODE will ever be added to that specific boolean state, which is very rare.

Answer (score 0):

```
$comments = $this->requestAction('/comments/latest');
foreach($comments as $comment) {
    echo $comment['Comment']['title'];
}
```

put this code in your ctp file