# How to call Controller function from webroot file in Cakephp?

Tags: cakephp

I want to call controller function from webroot files
i have a controller

```
 class AbsController extends AppController {
     function testfn($type){
        if($type>1) return 'Value is greater than one';
        else return 'Value is less than one';  
    } 
 }
```

file path is app/webroot/number.php.
In this file, I want to call `testfn` function.
Please tell me "How can I do this?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to use controller function in webroot file, you need to load cakephp bootstrap file first in number.php

```
if (!defined('DS')) {
define('DS', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);
}
if (!defined('ROOT')) {
define('ROOT', dirname(dirname(dirname(__FILE__))));
}
if (!defined('APP_DIR')) {
define('APP_DIR', basename(dirname(dirname(__FILE__))));
}
if (!defined('WEBROOT_DIR')) {
define('WEBROOT_DIR', basename(dirname(__FILE__)));
}
if (!defined('WWW_ROOT')) {
define('WWW_ROOT', dirname(__FILE__) . DS);
}
require_once('yourlocalpath/cakephp/lib/Cake/bootstrap.php');
require_once('yourlocalpath/cakephp/app/Controller/AbsController.php');
$user = new AbsController();
$user->testfn('2');
```

Comment: Hi, Sudhir sorry to say but your code is not working in Cakephp 3

Comment: Hi @NeerajRathod this code is for version 2. You have to update it in Cakephp 3

Comment: ya sudhir , I found the solution thank for your concern :)

Comment: Hi @NeerajRathod Welcome.

Answer (score 2):

This doesn't make much sense. Use the framework as it is intended to be used instead of doing weird things. Do the blog tutorial. This doesn't sound like you understand the very basics of how to use it.

If you insist on doing bad things and architecture look at the CakePHP file: **index.php**. You'll probably have to copy the complete bootstrap process of the framework to be able to properly instantiate a controller somewhere else and get it working right. Check the code of the frameworks' dispatcher as well. That's where the controllers get instantiated.

Comment: Hi Burzum, Yes i know this is not a proper flow. But you know burzum, In real world problem something you have to do this type of weird things to meet client requirement under timeline,
thank for taking out time for this :) burzum

Comment: This is just an excuse for writing bad code. You're producing unmaintainable code. There is for sure a better solution to his problem. You pile up terrible code until it crashes because you can't fix anything without having to work hours on it because you produced a huge mess. I've seen this multiple times before when I did code reviews. Worst case is this ends in an economical code ruin. We had one case were an Indian company estimated their own garbage code refactor by TWO YEARS. We rewrote the whole app in 3 month. Working with their code would have probably taken indeed 2 years.

Comment: I was facing the same situation, under a client requirement I had to leave the old page while people were adjusting to use the new platform. Not advised but real scenarios can come up with things like this.

Answer (score 2):

If you really want to do this, use curl:

```
    $ch = curl_init(); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://localhost/app/abs/testfn/1"); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
    $output = curl_exec($ch);  
    curl_close($ch);
```

But as said, I don't get it, why would you want to do this. Are you trying to create some webservice or something? If so, CakePHP has quite good tools for it: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/rest.html

Answer (score 0):

you can make requestaction call from view files.

try to make requestaction and check out that answer: [cakephp requestAction method View file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5581677/1531386)

```
$blogs = $this->requestAction('/blogs/index');
echo $blogs;
//or
var_dump($blogs);
```

in webroot files you can make fetch elements to include view files.

Comment: That won't work: He doesn't want to call a controller method from inside the frameworks scope and boundaries but instead he wants to call a controllers method directly from a php that is "disconnected" from the framework.